# I am unable to change default android theme to this Android Studio is showing "cannot resolve symbol" error

Tags: android, themes, android-manifest

This is the theme i wanted to use "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" in my app but for some reasonit keeps crashing my app.Can anyone point out the errors?.I changed the theme in values folder too it didn't work .
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="crystalball.com.example.android.crystlalball" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**This is logcat**:

```
08-30 15:10:48.220    1969-1969/crystalball.com.example.android.crystlalball I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-30 15:10:48.368    1969-1969/crystalball.com.example.android.crystlalball D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
08-30 15:10:48.368    1969-1969/crystalball.com.example.android.crystlalball E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: crystalball.com.example.android.crystlalball, PID: 1969
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{crystalball.com.example.android.crystlalball/crystalball.com.example.android.crystlalball.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:152)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:149)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at crystalball.com.example.android.crystlalball.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
device not found
```

Comment: What is your app's Android sdk version?

Comment: What is the error message? Paste a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space at the end of your string is causing the problem. Please remove the space after Fullscreen.

Comment: ahaha yes that worked out.Sorry  !!.Silly mistakes.Thank you everone that posted!!.

Comment: It worked but now it keeps crashing my app.Any idea why?

Comment: please post the log for the crash.

Comment: @user3847870 What does yours `MainActivity` extend? Change it to `Activity` and try.

Comment: @SrikarReddy thanks buddy it worked!!.Can you please state the reason why it happened?

Comment: @user3847870 In your log cat it says, `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`.

If your MainActivity extends `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`, it definitely uses support libraries (you can check the support libraries in the Gradle files).

And according to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#AndroidThemes), if you use support libraries,
**you must instead use the Theme.AppCompat themes**

Comment: You already have a custom theme in mind otherwise I would've advised you to change your theme to 

**Theme.AppCompat for the "dark" theme.**

**Theme.AppCompat.Light for the "light" theme.**

**Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar for the light theme with a dark action bar.**

Read the docs about [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html), you'll understand clearly.